How to remove blue border in Moveable element
I would like to remove the blue border that is around  element, that comes as the default option of Moveable element from 'react-moveable' library.
    <div id={"div element"}>
      <Moveable
        draggable={true}
        origin={false}
        target={pieceImage}
      />
      <img
        ref={pieceImage}
        src={pieceGraphics}
        alt={"img element"}
      />
    </div>

I tried adding custom CSS classes and styles for every component present above. Like border: none !important or/and outline: none !important, but it didn't change anything.

All these lines and circles are rendered separately under the element with the class .moveable-control-box. I suggest debugging this block yourself to understand what exactly needs to be hidden and how.
You can also consider one setting, hideDefaultLines which you can set to true to hide lines. However, it will still leave all these circles, which are necessary to resize/rotate the image.

Thanks hideDefaultLines solves the problem.
